# Multi-Line Records Reader (when start prefix = end prefix)

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I'm implementing Multi-Line Records Reader solution based on https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/patterns.html#multiLineRecords

I have the following flat file:

```
HEA;0013100345;2007-02-15
NCU;Smith;Peter;;T;20014539;F
BAD;;Oak Street 31/A;;Small Town;00235;IL;US
HEA;0013100345;2007-02-15
NCU;Smith;Peter;;T;20014539;F
HEA;0013100345;2007-02-15
```

HEA(and optionally NCU, BAD) must be converted to a single object.
However in my case I don't have "end" line, so "HEA" is a start of new Item and end of previous one at the same time.

Thanks to Dean Clark for the good suggestion below. This is java config of the solution:

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<FieldSet> readerFlat() {
    FlatFileItemReader<FieldSet> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("multirecord.txt"));
    reader.setLineMapper(compositeLineMapper());
    return reader;
}

@Bean
public SingleItemPeekableItemReader<FieldSet> readerPeek() {
    SingleItemPeekableItemReader<FieldSet> reader = new SingleItemPeekableItemReader<FieldSet>() {{
        setDelegate(readerFlat());
    }};
    return reader;
}

@Bean
public MultiLineCaseItemReader readerMultirecord() {
    MultiLineCaseItemReader multiReader = new MultiLineCaseItemReader() {{
        setDelegate(readerPeek());
    }};
    return multiReader;
}
```

Then in the custom `MultiLineCaseItemReader` your can do both `read()` and `peek()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the reference docs mention, you should create a custom implementation of `ItemReader` to wrap the `FlatFileItemReader`.

More specifically, you may want to extend `SingleItemPeekableItemReader` and use `FlatFileItemReader` as your delegate.

You'd `peek()` ahead to the next item. If it's part of your `current item`, great, go ahead and augment your item. If it's the next "header" line, then you've finished the item you're working and can return the `current item`.

Then, the next `read()` will start on the line you just peeked at without losing your place in the file or messing up restartability.

Comment: Thank you Dean! This is exactly what I was looking for. Wondering, why spring batch reference guide has nothing about SingleItemPeekableItemReader...

Comment: Dean, would you kindly modify the sentence "If it's the next "header" line, then the item you're working." because it sounds like some words are missing :)

Comment: thank you Dean! The last line helped me a lot and cleared a confusion for me.

Comment: @Dean - Could you please provide sample example ?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37123811/spring-batch-how-to-process-multiple-records-at-the-same-time-in-the-processor/37142450#37142450