# Aggregating processor or aggregating reader

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a requirement, which is like, I read items from a DB, if possible in a paging way where the items represent the later "batch size", I do some processing steps, like filtering etc. then I want to accumulate the items to send it to a rest service where I can send it to in batches, e.g. n of them at once instead one by one.

Parallelising it on the step level is what I am doing but I am not sure on how to get the batching to work, do I need to implement a reader that returns a list and a processor that receives a list? If so, I read that you will have not a proper account of number items processed.

I am trying to find a way to do it in the most appropriate spring batch way instead of hacking a fix, I also assume that I need to keep state in the reader and wondered if there is a better way not to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have something like an aggregating processor. Every single item that is read is processed as single item.

However, you can implement a Reader that groups items and forwards them as a whole group. to get an idea, how this could be done have a look at my answer to this question [Spring Batch Processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31930775/spring-batch-processor/31943265#31943265) or Dean Clark's answer here [Spring Batch-How to process multiple records at the same time in the processor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37123811/spring-batch-how-to-process-multiple-records-at-the-same-time-in-the-processor/37146018#37146018).

Both use a SpringBatch's SingleItemPeekableItemReader.