# Combine rows from 2 files and write to DB using Spring Batch

Tags: merge, spring-batch, composite

I have File1.csv, with the columns id,name,age. 
File2.csv has the columns id,designation. In both the files ID refers to same value and is unique.
Sample data
File1.csv

```
id    name    age
101   abc     30
102   def     25
```

File2.csv

```
id     designation
101    manager
102    Assistant manager
```

Spring batch should read the files simultaneously, combine the data and write to DB as below

```
id   name    age   designation
101  abc     30     manager
102  def     25     Assistant manager
```

How to read 2 files simultaneously in spring batch?

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement a Reader that merges the two files togehter.

Have a look at my answer here
[Aggregating processor or aggregating reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40389161/aggregating-processor-or-aggregating-reader/40395117#40395117)

where I have linked to other answers to a similar question

Comment: Will this work for 2 files with different columns and are not in sorted order?

Comment: No, that is not possible. You need to have an identifier column, which links the two elements together. And, because of the sequentiel reading, all sources must be ordered based in this id column. This also ensures the best possible performance that is attainable.