# How to read multiple CSV files in Spring Batch to merge the data for processing?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-batch

I’m new to Spring Batch and trying to get some guidance for below requirement.

#### Overall Requirement:

I’ve to get data from different systems, apply some business logic, save the result in DB.

Below is an example.

I need to read data from 3 CSV files.
First file – person.csv – contains name and id
Second File – address.csv – contains address info for each person. One person can have zero or multiple addresses.
Third File – employment.csv – contains employment info for each person. One person can have zero or multiple employers.

Here is some sample.

#### Person.csv### (total size is 8 millions)

"personID", "personName"

1,  Joey

2,  Chandler

3,  Ross

4,  Monica

#### Address.csv

"personID", "addressType", "state"

1,  residence,  NY

1,  mailing,    NC

2,  residence,  NY

4,  residence,  NY

4,  mailing,    DC

#### Employment.csv

"personID", "employerName"

1,  emp1

2,  emp2

2,  emp3

3,  emp4

Note: each file is sorted by person id.

To apply the business logic, I need to merge the data for each person, i.e, I need to merge person, address, employment data for one person to apply the logic.
Can you suggest any approach for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine rows from 2 files and write to DB using Spring Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40760001/combine-rows-from-2-files-and-write-to-db-using-spring-batch)

Comment: I think is not duplicate.  The solution in that sublink only for files with the same columns and order

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a 4 [step](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html), job.  You'll have to decide where the intermediate results of steps 1 to 3 should reside.

If the data from all the CSV files will fit in memory, then the intermediate results of steps 1 to 3 could just be a `Map`, with `personID` as the key.  If not, then the intermediate results of steps 1 to 3 should probably be written to a temp table in the database.

Assuming all data will fit in memory, create a bean which can be injected into the ItemWriters of steps 1 to 3, for example:

```
// in a config class...
// assuming PersonID is of type Long
// Assuming Person class has appropriate attributes
Map<Long, Person> people = new HashMap<>();
```

Step 1:

- ItemReader - reads the next Person.CSV row and creates a Person
  instance
- ItemProcessor - nothing to do - pass the Person instance to
  the ItemWriter
- ItemWriter - adds the Person instance to the `people`
  Map (or intermediate table).

Step 2:

- ItemReader - reads the next Address.CSV row and creates an Address instance
- ItemProcessor - nothing to do - pass the Address instance to the ItemWriter
- ItemWriter - adds the Address to the related Person from the `people` Map (or intermediate table).  TODO: what should happen if there is an Address for a person that does not exist?

Step 3:

- ItemReader - reads the next Employment.CSV row and creates an Employment instance
- ItemProcessor - nothing to do - pass the Employment instance to the ItemWriter
- ItemWriter - adds the Employment to the related Person from the `people` Map (or intermediate table).  TODO: what should happen if there is an Employment for a person that does not exist?

Since there is nothing for ItemProcessor to do in steps 1 to 3, it might be better to use a Tasklet.

Also, steps 1 to 3 could be done in parallel.  It would probably increase performance, but there would be added complexity to ensure `people` is correctly populated.

Step 4:

- ItemReader - reads the next element of `people` (or composite object from intermediate tables)
- ItemProcessor - apply business logic
- ItemWriter - write result to database

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your input.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your input. The payload size for my batch is very high. I'll have about 8 million persons and don't have any staging table. So, I won't be able to handle in memory. Since, no staging table is there, i believe the only option i have is to go with intermediate csv/xml/json. which will increase the processing time.

Comment: Use the database to store the intermediate results of steps 1 to 3.  See the [readers/writers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#readersAndWriters) which make it painless to handle interactions with the common database platforms.