# how to read multiple flat files with different headers and process them at once using spring batch

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have multiple files with different headers as shown below. The number of fields in each file is not the same. So technically we can't use spring batch `MultiResourceItemReader` to read them.

```
file1.txt
--------------
Id|Name

file2.txt
-----------
id|Dept

file2.txt
--------------
id|Salary|desig
```

After reading all the files, I want the data of all the files to be available and would like to pass to `processor` to process them and do some lookups on data based on `id` and finally generate a file something like below

```
outputfile.txt

id|name|dept|salary|desig
```

Without processing them we can write them to the output file. But the only concern here is how to read the data from all the files and store data in `Map` or any data structure, and then apply business logic, and then write data to a single file. Is there a way to read these files parallel and store data that is available to the processor or next step?

Comment: @gurioso, I agree with you on the approach. But due to timelines, we are not supposed to create any tables and load data

Comment: @gurioso, it is development timelines. It is an example but my actual fields and lookups are a little complex. I need to apply business rules, some data conversions. also, the code should be testable and maintainable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine rows from 2 files and write to DB using Spring Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40760001/combine-rows-from-2-files-and-write-to-db-using-spring-batch)

Comment: staging tables is the way to go, but looks like this is not an option for you.

Comment: The solution in that sublink works only for files with the same columns and order