# Can we process the records read from two different flat files in one processor?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I need to process the data read from two different files and need to store in the Mongo DB. Since one step under the job cannot have multiple readers, I thought of having two different readers, but how can we merge the data read from two different files from two different steps and in which step we need to implement the processor and writer.

I tried implementing a flow with split of having two different steps where each handles reading the records from two files. Since they are completely different files with difference in their headers.

```
@Bean
public Job job(JobRepository jobRepository) {
    return new JobBuilder("job", jobRepository)
        .start(splitFlow())
        .next(step4())
        .build()        //builds FlowJobBuilder instance
        .build();       //builds Job instance
}

@Bean
public Flow splitFlow() {
    return new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("splitFlow")
        .split(taskExecutor())
        .add(flow1(), flow2())
        .build();
}

@Bean
public Flow flow1() {
    return new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("flow1")
        .start(step1()) // where step1 handles the reading of one flatFile.
        .build();
}

@Bean
public Flow flow2() {
    return new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("flow2")
        .start(step3()) // where step3 handles the reading of another flatFile.
        .build();
}

@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("spring_batch");
}
```

Now, for each record in the first file, I need to lookup for id value in the second file and then store in the DB.

```
file1.csv
--------------
Id| First Name| Last Name

file2.csv
-----------
id| Dept

Result
--------------
id| First Name| Last Name| Dept
```

How can we combine the data read from two readers and process them under one processor?
Does anyone have any suggestions on how the job should be configured in this scenario?

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59165083/how-to-read-multiple-flat-files-with-different-headers-and-process-them-at-once) is somewhat similar to mine, [@techi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2592089/techi), I'd like to know whether you got your question answered or do you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure how you can do it with spring-batch but doing this using an embedded database such as [H2](https://h2database.com/html/main.html) is extremely easy. Assuming transforming the two files from `txt` to `csv` is not a problem you just load the two files into two tables and join them by `ID`

```
CREATE table_1 TEST AS SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('file1.csv');
CREATE table_2 TEST AS SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('file2.csv');
SELECT t1.first_name, t1.last_name, t2.dept
  FROM table_1 t1
  JOIN table_2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

Then depending on your requirements, you can write them back to a file or do whatever you need.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, but I'm looking for configuring the job using spring batch.

Comment: I haven't used Spring batch commercially and apart from reading a bit o documentation my knowledge is limited. This said I cant't see why in spring batch step 1 you cannot create table_1 in step 2 create table_2 and in step 3 join them. Just a thought.

Comment: I know for sure spring batch expects a database to be there

Comment: As far as my knowledge is concerned regarding spring batch, every step need to have a reader and writer for sure and processor is optional. If we think in the way you said, like step1 for reading from file1.csv and step2 for reading file2.csv, I'm not sure on what to do in the writer for step1 and step2. Think like  we can overcome that using noop implementation for writer in step1 & step2, during merging in the step3, not sure again on whether I'll get the data that we read from both the step1 and step2 & how can we access that in step3, and what to implement in the reader of step3.