# Spring Batch - Read from Relational DS and CSV

Tags: spring-batch

I am working on **Spring Boot + Spring Batch** example. Where I want to read data `(Employee Data)` from **Oracle Datasource** and `Department Data` from **CSV** and load it into MongoDB as Employee schema holds embeeded Department details.

I am not getting sure if AnstractItemStreamItemReader is the good choice ?

Answer (score 0):

An item reader is designed to read from a single source. You can't read from two sources at the same time, unless you are ready to write a custom reader. What you can do is create a staging table where you load the content of the file, then join data between employee/department tables and write the result in MongoDB.

A similar question but for two files here: [Combine rows from 2 files and write to DB using Spring Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40760001/combine-rows-from-2-files-and-write-to-db-using-spring-batch).

Comment: Thanks ! I want to read one from Relational and other from CSV, from your example its not that clear. But Custom Reader have a capability to do so. Can you please share sample code ? Else I was thinking in Custom Writer read the CSV and create the final object there and save it, What you say ?