# Spring Batch - Read Two CSV files and Compare

Tags: spring-batch

I have a use case where i need to read two csv files with one unique column and create one output csv..do we have any out of the box solution that we have with spring batch

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine rows from 2 files and write to DB using Spring Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40760001/combine-rows-from-2-files-and-write-to-db-using-spring-batch)

Comment: My two files are not sorted..I do have an identifier in both the files though.

Comment: What does sorting add to the equation? Are you trying to join these two files on a given key? Spring Batch provides a toolbox with two types of tasks: a simple tasklet and a chunk-oriented tasklet. It is up to you to come up with an algorithm and implement it with Spring Batch' facilities. How would you do that *without* Spring Batch? Please share your attempt and I will try to help you implement it with Spring Batch.

Comment: Please edit your question and paste your formatted code there. It will be more readable than pasting it in comments.

Comment: 1.Read fileA convert to inputList  
2.Read fileB convert to inputMap key will be the unique id that is present in both the files value will be the object   
3.Create a final list by iterating the inputList and matching with key in inputMap

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please start by reading this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking.

Comment: I used SuperCsv to do something like this long ago, i.e. read an entire file into a map in a reader and then read a second file and add/enhance records using the in memory map. Sort of similar to having one Csv left join onto records from the other. It was a very custom thing to do and memory sizing may grow boundlessly so it's not always a good idea to even try.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the below three bean in an config file to read and process the two csvs,

```
@Autowired
FlatFileReaderFactory<CsvFile1Dto> csvFile1ReaderFactory;

@Autowired
FlatFileReaderFactory<CsvFile2Dto> csvFile2ReaderFactory;

@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<CsvFile1Dto> csvFile1Reader() {
    LOGGER.debug("CsvFile1Reader Bean has bean created");
    String[] columnNames = new String[] {
            "userId",
            "firstName",
            "lastName",
            "workExperience[0].companyName"
    };
    return csvFile1ReaderFactory.reader("CsvFile1Input.csv", columnNames, CsvFile1Dto.class);
}

@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<CsvFile2Dto> csvFile2Reader() {
    LOGGER.debug("dcdirectUserListReader Bean has bean created");
    String[] columnNames = new String[] {
            "userId",
            "addressLine1",
            "addressLine2",
            "country"
    };

    return csvFile2ReaderFactory.reader("CsvFile2Input.csv", columnNames,
            CsvFile2Dto.class);
}

@Bean
public ItemProcessor<CsvFile1Dto, UserInfo> combinedUserInfoItemProcessor() {
    LOGGER.debug("combinedUserInfoItemProcessor Bean has bean created");
    return new CombinedUserInfoItemProcessor();
}
```

Add the below Generic ReaderFactory,

```
public class FlatFileReaderFactory<T> {
    
    public FlatFileItemReader<T> reader(String fileInput,String[] columnNames, Class<T> targetType) {
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<T>()
                .name("FlatFileItemReader")
                .resource(new ClassPathResource(fileInput))
                .linesToSkip(1) // to skip the header while reading
                .delimited()
                .names(columnNames)
                .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<T>() {
                    {
                        setTargetType(targetType);
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }
}
```

Add the below ReaderFactoryConfig,

```
@Configuration
public class ReaderFactoryConfig {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReaderFactoryConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public FlatFileReaderFactory<UserInfo> userInfoReaderFactory(){
        LOGGER.debug("UserInfoReaderFactory Bean has bean created");
        return new FlatFileReaderFactory<>();
    }

    @Bean
    public FlatFileReaderFactory<CsvFile1Dto> csvFile1ReaderFactory(){
        LOGGER.debug("csvFile1ReaderFactory Bean has bean created");
        return new FlatFileReaderFactory<>();
    }

    @Bean
    public FlatFileReaderFactory<CsvFile2Dto> csvFile2ReaderFactory(){
        LOGGER.debug("csvFile1ReaderFactory Bean has bean created");
        return new FlatFileReaderFactory<>();
    }

}
```

In the processor we are going to merge the two csv,

```
public class CombinedUserInfoItemProcessor
        implements ItemProcessor<CsvFile1Dto, UserInfo> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CombinedUserInfoItemProcessor.class);

    @Autowired
    FlatFileItemReader<CsvFile2Dto> csvFile2Reader;

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public UserInfo process(@NonNull CsvFile1Dto csvFile1Dto) {
        LOGGER.info(
                "<--------------------------------- Processing CsvFile1Dto userId: {} --------------------------------->",
                csvFile1Dto.getUserId());
        LOGGER.debug("started processing the CsvFile1Dto {}", csvFile1Dto);
        // in batch spring automatically calls this open method but now we have to on
        // our own
        csvFile2Reader.open(new ExecutionContext());
        UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
        CsvFile2Dto csvFile2Dto;
        try {
            while ((csvFile2Dto = csvFile2Reader.read()) != null) {

                LOGGER.debug("Comparing CsvFile1Dto: {} == CsvFile2Dto: {}",
                        csvFile1Dto.getUserId(),
                        csvFile2Dto.getUserId());
                if (csvFile1Dto.getUserId().equals(csvFile2Dto.getUserId())) {
                    LOGGER.debug("Matched {} == {}", csvFile1Dto.getUserId(),
                            csvFile2Dto.getUserId());
                    // implemment the logic to update user info
                    userInfo.setPlansponsorId(csvFile1Dto.getUserId());
                    userInfo.setFirstName(csvFile1Dto.getFirstName());
                    //add rest of CSV file 1 fields
                    userInfo.setAddressLine1(csvFile2.getAddressLine1);
                    //add rest of CSV file 2 fields
                    csvFile2Reader.close();
                    return userInfo;
                }
            }
        csvFile2Reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception Occured while processing {}, message: {}", csvFile1Dto.getUserId(),
                    e.getMessage());
            LOGGER.debug("Exception Occured while processing {}, message: {}", csvFile1Dto.getUserId(), e);
        }
        return userInfo;
    }

}
```