# Initialize an object from multiple input file data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have 2 fixed-length flat files F1 and F2 containing data (id, A, B) and (id, C, D) respectively.

I am trying to instantiate an object `Foo f = new Foo (id, A, B, C, D).`

How can I achieve this feat with spring batch. I don't have access to any DB so I can't insert Foo(id, A, B) into a staging table and then update the missing values.

Thank you so much :)

Comment: Why would you want to use a database to stage it.    That is a LOT of slow blocking I/O and a major failure point.    Spring already does this.   Just need to create a flow with multiple steps.   Step 1 loads file one and populated an object.    That step's output goes to step 2 which load the next file and populates the other fields and then output's to what ever you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @BrianC, I'm just starting with Spring batch, how can I pass the output of step 1 to step 2?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40760001/combine-rows-from-2-files-and-write-to-db-using-spring-batch) answer your question? That said, do you really need Spring Batch for that? Something like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113898/how-to-merge-two-files-based-on-the-matching-of-two-columns should do the trick for you. Once that sorted, you can use a `SystemCommandTasklet` to merge files and then use a chunk-oriented step to process the merged file containing prepared data like you expect it.

Comment: Thank you so much @MahmoudBenHassine, I will read attentively these threads, attempt to properly implement a solution, and get back with an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Mahmoud Ben Hassine, using an awk script solved my issue, here's my script

```
awk 'NR==FNR  
{dossier[$3] = $0;next}
 {
    printf("<client>\n");   
    printf "<rev>%s</rev>\n<pdd>%s</pdd>\n",$0,dossier[$9];
    print("</client>")
  }' pdddos.txt revass.txt > output.txt
sed -i '1s/^/<clients>\n/' output.txt
sed -i -e '$a</clients>' output.txt
```