# Create an ItemReader Class which gathers data from sub item readers

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-integration, spring-batch

Currently I have multiple Item readers for individual Database queries. I want to get all of that information into a single Object. Is there a type of ItemReader which can do this for me? I'd like the Processor and Writer to handle that object after the reader reads in as a single object. So basically I need to create an object from a group of ItemReaders and use it from that point on as my only data source to process and write.
One thing to note is that I cannot change the existing ItemReaders due to it being a larger part of a project.

Comment: I would say that your approach is flawed to begin with and trying to wrap those listeners into a single one is more trouble then it is worth.

Comment: Currently I have Field1Reader, Field2Reader, Field3Reader, and I want a super Item reader, which could insert data into an Object I have created

Comment: As stated your approach seems to be flawed to begin with. Why not write a single query to retrieve everything in one go... Instead of trying to sync 3 readers in a single one.

Comment: I am extracting the information from a lot of different tables (about 16). it would need a lot of SQL Joins if I need just one query for all the info

Comment: So what, that is what SQL is good at. Which in the end is probably faster even then 16 individual queries which you are trying to sync together... You can then simply use the default support in Spring Batch to map things.

Comment: Why are you not using one `ItemReader` to provide the id of what you want, then use an `ItemProcessor` to enrich it?  You know you can use more than one `ItemProcessor` via the `CompositeItemProcessor` allowing you to build more of a chain of processing in your step.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you cannot change existing coded, I would avoid using multiple readers and instead look at using an ORM framework like Hibernate in a brand new reader?

Alternatively, create a new reader using `JdbcCursorItemReader` and just join the 3 (or more) tables together for your driving cursor and map the result set to your custom object. If the joins will cause the cursor to return multiple rows per object, I first would suggest to go back and look at Hibernate. If Hibernate isn't an option, you could extend the `SingleItemPeekableItemReader` to iterate through the cursor until you've fully built your objects.

[Example using `SingleItemPeekableItemReader`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37142450/6215069).