# Spring Batch: Reading Multi-Line Record from Flat File

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have the following problem to solve:

There is a flat file to read, but the information is unfortunately spread over two rows. So i need to merge these two rows.
I thought about creating an incomplete object first and then add the information from the next row. Then move to the next couple. But i don't really see how to manage that.

Is there a way to read two lines and then process, or to remember an object from one to another step. I'm quite confused.

Any hint would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Check the spring batch samples, especially the multiline one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for using a `SingleItemPeekableItemReader`. Check out [this older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37142450/6215069) for an example.

Comment: Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63674370/caused-by-org-springframework-batch-item-file-transform-incorrectlinelengthexce ?