# Java Spring MultiLineItemReader To read Complex file having multiple records of same type

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am new to Spring and trying to read a complex file using `FlatFileItemReader` in Spring batch. The input file has structure as below. The sample below is one records and file has many records like this. Line starting with H is a Header Record and with F is a footer records. In between there are transaction records of type 10500, 10501, 405, 505. I am able to read this file using `MultiLineItemReader`.

I have created `FieldSetMapper` and `Tokenizer` and able to parse the file and get to individual fields. Only issue I am facing is that for records types 10500 and 10501 they can appear multiple times in between Header and Footer and when I am reading the file I am just getting the last read values and the previous records are just not appearing in reading. I know I am doing something silly but not able to understand. Has anybody had any experience reading such type of file.

```
H00025888222    444233DD            33232323232

105000000             0000                    0

10501                  1                2222222

105000000             0000                    1

10501                  1                 2222223

40500                                     1222222

50500                                          21
F00555              5555                        0
```

Comment: Please post code of your reader so we can point out possible issue with it.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and with that newly acquired knowledge please improve your question. (Tip: at least include some configuration and/or code to show what you have instead of just dumping a file and expecting an answer).

Answer (score 0):

If the you just have multiple types of lines, but the lines are each standalone, then `PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper` is probably what you're looking for.

```
<bean id="itemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="resource" value="#{jobParameters['input.file']}" />
    <property name="lineMapper" ref="patternMatchingMapper" />
    <property name="strict" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="patternMatchingMapper" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper">
    <property name="tokenizers">
        <map>
            <entry key="LINEA*" value-ref="tokenizerA" />
            <entry key="LINEB*" value-ref="tokenizerB" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="fieldSetMappers">
        <map>
            <entry key="*" value-ref="beanWrapperFieldSetMapper" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

If they are related (multiple lines need to be combined to make one object, you make consider `SingleItemPeekableItemReader`, [described briefly here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36897858/6215069)).