# Mapping an array in the Name property for BeanWrapperFieldExtractor

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I have a Record bean. In that I am using an array of different objects. While writing the data into a CSV file I am not able to map that array for the `Name` property of `BeanWrapperFieldExtractor`.

How can I map the array of Address in `BeanWrapperFieldExtractor`? Or is there any alternate way to solve this issue?

Comment: <property name="fieldExtractor">
    <bean
   class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
   <property name="names" value="refId, name, age, csvDob, income" />
     </bean>
  </property>

Comment: Does each address need to go on its own line in the CSV? I assume you don't want a variable number of fields per line depending on how many addresses each person has...

Comment: @DeanClark Yeah I wanted to store each address in a different line with the corresponding parent record.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36897858/6215069) dealing with files where multiple lines apply to the same record. Basically you would leverage a `SingleItemPeekableItemReader`, and each parent record would be augmented by the following addresses lines.